# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer este FETCH para enviar una imagen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

```js
fetch (`http://localhost:3000/api/demos/create/${this.state.name}/${this.state.img}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
```

El problema con este método es que me envía esta request y está mal.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/demos/create/dasda/C:/fakepath/Screen%20Shot%202016-12-13%20at%205.43.40%20PM.png
```

Por ejemplo, desde el 'postman' lo envío como 'body' y funciona pero aquí no, ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Estas tomando el parh guardado como C:/fackepath, que te da chrome, lo que quiere decir que o estas tomando la ruta de la imagen desde el cliente, o guardaste la ruta path del cliente y no la del servidor... para poder usar imagenes las tienes que tener alojadas en el servidor, no en el cliente.

Comment: Es que lo tengo corriendo en local

Comment: Y esa ruta me la da chrome al subir la foto con el form nomas

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar algo así:

**En HTML podrías tener algo como lo siguiente:**

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Aquí al hacer el submit se invocará a la función handleSubmit que debes generar, por otro lado es muy importante que los input tengan la propiedad **name**.

Una vez hecho esto se crearía la función ej:

**En este ejemplo se toman todos los valores del formulario directamente.**

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); //Previene que se recargue la página al hacer submit.
  const formData = new FormData(event.target); //event.target es el formulario
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/demos/create", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  });
};
```

**En este ejemplo se agregarían usando los estados**, se crea un nuevo **FormData** y luego se hace append pasandole el valor de los estados. Para que funcione al hacer el onChange del fileInput deberás guardar "**event.target.files[0]**" en el estado correspondiente.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); //Previene que se recargue la página al hacer submit.
  const formData = new FormData(); //event.target es el formulario
  formData.append("name", this.state.name);
  formData.append("name", this.state.image);
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/demos/create", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  });
};
```

Una vez hecho esto lo que restaría es recibir la información en el backend y hacer lo deseado con ella, para esto puede que necesites utilizar algún recurso como formidable y dentro del parseo quedarán disponibles los files y los fields.

Adjunto link a documentación de FormData:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData

Adjunto link a formidable en npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que leo en tus comentarios:
El error que veo es que aun que sea local la aplicación el servidor es localhost (que se disfraza como servidor externo), a pensar de ser local tienes que tomar la imagen de una ruta del servidor, por eso te da error al agregar la imagen.

En el servidor no hay ninguna ruta que sea `C:\fakepath`.

Si quieres mostrar la imagen tienes que tener la imagen dentro de tu proyecto/servidor y poner la ruta de esta en el servidor.
para que funcione (suponiendo que tienes la pagina en raíz) debe ser algo como `images/myimage.png`

Agrega la imagen al proyecto y usala desde la ruta del servidor para que aparezca.

Espero te funcione

Comment: Pero si esuna imagen que selecciona un user desde un from, como la voy a tener en el servidor?

Comment: de ser así el form tiene que tener el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data ` y en vez de mandar solo la imagen manda el formulario completo, y ya desde servidor lo recuperas